# Form of Markov Inequality proof

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, random-variables, expected-value

Prove the following lemma for any nonnegative random variable X and real number ${\epsilon}$ > 0.

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X>n \epsilon)<\frac{1}{\epsilon} \mathbb{E}(X) \leqslant 1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X>n \epsilon)
$$

1. **Define** $Y$:
   $Y$ = $n\epsilon$ if $ n\epsilon < X \leq (n+1)\epsilon$, $ 0 $ if $ X = 0$
2. **Expectation of Y**:
   $ \mathbb{E}(Y) = \epsilon \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \mathbb{P}(X > n\epsilon)$
3. **Lower Bound**:
   $ \mathbb{E}(Y) \leq \mathbb{E}(X) \Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X > n\epsilon) < \frac{1}{\epsilon} \mathbb{E}(X)$
4. **Upper Bound**:
   $\mathbb{E}(Y) \geq \epsilon \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X > n\epsilon) \Rightarrow \frac{1}{\epsilon} \mathbb{E}(X) \leq 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X > n\epsilon)$

Result:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X>n \epsilon)<\frac{1}{\epsilon} \mathbb{E}(X) \leqslant 1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X>n \epsilon)
$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Henry put my attempt in

Answer (score 1):

1. **First Inequality**:
   Using the fact that $\mathbb{E}(X)$ = $\int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X > x) \,dx$, we can partition the integral:
   $$
      \mathbb{E}(X) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{(n-1)\epsilon}^{n\epsilon} \mathbb{P}(X > n\epsilon) \,dx \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \epsilon \mathbb{P}(X > n\epsilon)
     $$
   Thus:
   $$
      \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X>n \epsilon)<\frac{1}{\epsilon} \mathbb{E}(X)
    $$
2. **Second Inequality**:
   We can write:
   $$
      \frac{1}{\epsilon} \mathbb{E}(X) = \frac{1}{\epsilon} \left( \int_{0}^{\epsilon} \mathbb{P}(X > x) \,dx + \int_{\epsilon}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X > x) \,dx \right) \leq 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X > n\epsilon)
     $$
   Thus:
   $$
      \frac{1}{\epsilon} \mathbb{E}(X) \leqslant 1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X>n \epsilon)
   $$
   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X>n \epsilon)<\frac{1}{\epsilon} \mathbb{E}(X) \leqslant 1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X>n \epsilon)
   $$

Answer (score 1):

(**Method of Indicators**)

The the terms of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1_{\{X > n\epsilon\}}(\omega)$ are all $1$ for $n\ge 1$ with $n<X(\omega)/\epsilon$,
but $0$ for all larger $n$. Therefore
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1_{\{X > n\epsilon\}}(\omega)\le X(\omega)/\epsilon.
$$
This is an equality unless $X(\omega)/\epsilon$ is an integer. Consequently, adding in a $1$ to account for this possibility, we also

have
$$
X(\omega)/\epsilon \le 1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1_{\{X > n\epsilon\}}(\omega).
$$
Writing this as a pair of  inequalities between random variables:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1_{\{X > n\epsilon\}}\le X/\epsilon\le 1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1_{\{X > n\epsilon\}}.\qquad\qquad (1)
$$
But
$$
\Bbb E\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1_{\{X >n\epsilon\}}\right]
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Bbb E[1_{\{X >n\epsilon\}}]
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Bbb P[X >n\epsilon],
$$
so the assertion follows upon taking expectations in (1).